# Scripting language with Objective-C syntax

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, scripting

So for a while I have been looking around for scripting languages that one can embed into C/C++ applications, and I have grown very satisfied with [AngelScript](http://angelcode.com). It recently learned the ability to pass named parameters:

```
// Example:
MyClass factory(int param1, float param2) {...}
factory(param1: 10, param2: 3.103);
```

So this makes an ObjC syntax very close. But I would like to know if a currently developed scripting language exists, that implements more of the Objective-C syntax?

If not, I will have to see if I can write my own, although it would be my first.

I do know about Objective-J, by the way. I am just loking for something to use within C/C++ applications.

Comment: [F-Script](http://www.fscript.org/) is based on Smalltalk as ObjC is.